# Disable Bitcoin core JSON-RPC server?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

Is it possible to disable JSON-RPC server ? It seems like it's always on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RPC server can be disabled by using the `-server=0` option or adding `server=0` to your bitcoin.conf file.

It is enabled by default when using `bitcoind`, but disabled by default when using `bitcoin-qt`.